# Unable to select a value from drop down in cucumber capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber with capybara to automate the web application. i have to select a value from a drop down , but many time i am getting an error like; "wrong argument type String (expected Array) (TypeError)"

I tried with:
1.

```
second_option_xpath = ".//*[@id='selecttype']/option[2]"  
second_option = find(:xpath, second_option_xpath).text
select(second_option, :from => 'selecttype')
```

2.

```
select "Selenium Core", :from => 'selecttype'
```

3.

```
page.find_and_select_option("selecttype", 2)
```

4.

```
select( "selecttype", {"Selenium Core" => 2})
```

PAGE SOURCE IS SOMETHING LIKE:

```
<select id="selecttype"> 
<option value="Selenium IDE">Selenium IDE</option> 
<option value="Selenium Code">Selenium Core</option> 
<option value="Selenium RC">Selenium RC</option> 
<option value="Selenium Grid">Selenium Grid</option> 
</select>"
```

Please suggest where i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I tried your 2nd solution with a page that had the source you provided, but it selected the option as expected (ie unable to reproduce your problem). Is there something else on the page that is causing the conflict? What version of Capybara are you using?

Comment: Your second option - "Selenium Code" doesn't match the text "Selenium Core" which may be causing your mismatch

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried

```
page.select('Selenium Core', :from => 'selecttype')
```

Comment: It worked for me. Besides @Atin didn`t accepted the answer, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

As RobertH suggests, you should use something like page.select, where page is a Capybara::Session instance.

When you call select in your code, you are invoking a method of the Kernel module, which is mixed in the basic Object class, which every class inherits from.

This method expects 4 parameters, 3 of them are arrays of IO objects; that's the reason why it complains about wrong arguments.